# How can I tell if a Bluetooth device got connected Without the bluetooth permission?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm working on an app that have audio calls in it
(some of them use Bluetooth)

I know I can check if a device is connected or Got connected
by using a `BroadcastReceiver` together with the `android.permission.BLUETOOTH`
permission

but if you will look into applications like messenger
and have a call
they know that you connected Bluetooth headphones to the call (show you a popup and move the call to the headset)

Without even having Bluetooth permission in their app,
in the messenger app settings, you don't have a Bluetooth permission

Is there another way to identify when Bluetooth headphones are connected and move audio there
Without the need to call Bluetooth in the permissions?

Answer (score 2):

You can used registerAudioDeviceCallback from AudioManager.

> Registers an AudioDeviceCallback object to receive notifications of changes to the set of connected audio devices.

This will not require any permission from bluetooth. I believe this is how other apps are detecting bluetooth devices during call.

```
(getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager).run {
        registerAudioDeviceCallback(object : AudioDeviceCallback() {
            override fun onAudioDevicesAdded(addedDevices: Array<out AudioDeviceInfo>?) {
                // Device Added
            }

            override fun onAudioDevicesRemoved(removedDevices: Array<out AudioDeviceInfo>?) {
                // Device Removed
            }
        }, null)
    }
```

Comment: this code doesn't compile, can you improve the answer in code ? is it java ? kotlin ?

Comment: it is kotlin. Its compellable code. @ChiefMadog

Comment: @ChiefMadog It seems like this is a more accurate answer and the correct way. Not mine. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53284715/14577209) contains a java implementation of the same code. Dont use the `updateAuxStatus()`. You can refer if it needed.

Answer (score 0):

This is a system-level operation in Android, and apps can detect Bluetooth devices that are already paired with the device without needing to request any special permissions. When a Bluetooth headset is paired with an Android device, it registers itself with the Android Bluetooth stack, which exposes information about the device to all apps on the device. Apps can then use the Bluetooth APIs provided by the Android SDK to query this information and detect the presence of the headset.

You can use the following code to get notified when a bluetooth headset is connected without requesting `android.permission.BLUETOOTH` permission,

```
public class HeadsetBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG)) {
        int state = intent.getIntExtra("state", -1);
        if (state == 1) {

            // Headset is plugged in
            
        } else if (state == 0) {

            // Headset is unplugged
           
        }
    }
}
}
```

To register the `ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG`,

```
HeadsetBroadcastReceiver receiver = new HeadsetBroadcastReceiver();
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG);
registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

*Note that if you want to perform Bluetooth discovery to find new devices, you will need to request the `android.permission.BLUETOOTH` permission in your app's manifest.

Comment: thanks for this comment, but how do they pass the audio to the headphones without that permission also ?

Comment: Use `AudioManager` to switch the audio routing when the headset is plugged in.

Comment: by the way that code needs the BLUETOOTH_CONNECT permission so it will need BT permission to be used it wont work without it

Comment: Yes but it is not a permission that you need to acquire from the user as in `android.permission.BLUETOOTH`. Just like you are adding internet permission to your application.